# How to dynamically pass values such as images and multiline texts to a wiki page which needs to be rendered in XSLT

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I have a requirement where I have a list which contains 4 columns named

1.Title   2.Image  3.Short Description    4.Full Description.

Now my requirement is that I need to display this list in a webpart which will initially display *Title*, *Image* and *Short Description* column values with a *Read more* hyperlink.

Upon clicking this *Read more* hyperlink, the control needs to be transferred to a wiki page where I have to display all the content of the respective item whose *Read more* hyperlink was clicked.

Can we do this by writing a template in ITEMSTLYE.XSL and if yes, then how?

PS: I am not allowed to use articles page to do so and i am pretty new to this.

Comment: Why a wiki page? Do these wiki pages exist for each of the list items? Or do you want to display the content of the list item in an existing wiki page? What elements does the wiki page already have? What should happen with that wiki page after the content is displayed? Please provide a bit more detail about the context and logic flow.

Comment: Also, you tagged this with [Content-Query-Web-Part]. There may be other web parts more suitable to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to use a CQWP you can do this by creating a custom template in the ItemStyle.xsl.

I usually do this by copying the standard ItemStyle.xsl file, adding a CQWP to a page then in SharePoint Designer I show the properties of the web part and tell it to use the copy of the ItemStyle.xsl.  You can then edit this as needed to create your custom template without any impact on standard CQWPs.

In this case, you should also create a custom page with a web part to display the details when you click the link.  Filter this web part by a query string parameter (eg ID) and then pass this parameter to the page when you click the link.

So in your ItemStyle.xsl you will have a link something like:

```
<a href="CustomPage.aspx?ID={@ID}><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></a>
```

Then on your detail page you create a parameter on your web part and filter where ID=[ID].

As Teylyn has indicated, you could also use a List/Data view or search web part to achieve the same thing but the concept is the same.